# Cant make PDO_sqlite working php

Tags: php, wordpress, sqlite, pdo

I am developing a website. I need to use PDO. I ran `phpinfo();` and it said:

```
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x    enabled
SQLite Library               3.8.10.2
```

Although writing

```
$pdo = new PDO("path/to/db.db");
```

Gives me error if as this function doesn't exist.

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver`.

Am I doing something wrong? (also that db file is sqlite 3 format). Any advice? Thanks ! (btw my website is made with wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$pdo = new PDO("sqlite:path/to/db.sqlite");`

2nd result from Google http://henryranch.net/software/ease-into-sqlite-3-with-php-and-pdo/

Comment: yep my bad but I am still getting errror:

 `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file`

Comment: Check your permissions. As a stop gap, you could chmod 777 the file.